# How to keep few inputs horizontally using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website and I want to keep few inputs horizontally.
This is my CSS code

```
  .input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0 20px;
}

input {
     display: inline block;
     width: 12%;
     background: #EAF6F6;

  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  border: 0px solid #757575;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

label {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4285f4;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  width:14%;
}

.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #4285f4;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}

input:focus ~ .bar:before,
input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}

.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

input:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}

/* animations */
@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from { background: #4285f4; }
  to   { width: 0; background: transparent; }
}
@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from { background: #4285f4; }
  to   { width: 0; background: transparent; }
}
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from { background: #4285f4; }
  to   { width: 0; background: transparent; }
}
```

This is my HTML code

```
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" required>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label>Quantity</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" required>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label>price</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" required>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label>Total</label>
</div>


 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" required>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label>Quantity</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" required>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label>price</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" required>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label>Total</label>
</div>
```

But all inputs are in vertically. As this[image: Actually now]

But I Expect like this
[image: Actually I expect]

I tried several ways. But unable to do. How to solve it. I found some bootstrap solutions. But I Do not expect Bootstrap. Expect pure CSS.

Comment: Why do you have `<body>` right in the middle of your document?

Comment: <body> tag removed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the inputs you wish to be displayed horizontally on the page within a flex group div.
See the css class `flex-group` in the example snippit below

[Css-Tricks on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
[Mozilla flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
/* display:flex for this class */
.flex-group {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px auto; /* set to 10px auto here */
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto; /* set margin to auto here */
}

input {
  display: inline block;
  background: #EAF6F6;
  width: 90%; /* set to 80% width */
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  border: 0px solid #757575;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

label {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

input:focus~label,
input:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4285f4;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 14%;
}

.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #4285f4;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}

input:focus~.bar:before,
input:focus~.bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}

.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

input:focus~.highlight {
  -webkit-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}


/* animations */

@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #4285f4;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #4285f4;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #4285f4;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

This is my HTML code
```

```html
<div class="flex-group"><!--/ added div with class of flex-group => display: flex; /-->
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Quantity</label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>price</label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Total</label>
  </div>
</div><!--/ END flex-group /-->
<div class="flex-group"><!--/ start new flex-group class /-->
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Quantity</label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>price</label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Total</label>
  </div>
</div><!--/ END flex-group /-->
```

Comment: But how to reduce the gap of this two rows. Help me.

Comment: If you make your width a hard percentage in CSS, it will need to be changed to accommodate the amount of elements you have within your parent flex element. I set the width of the input to 33%.

Comment: Are you referring to the padding / margin on top and bottom of the rows?

Comment: Ok. its solved . Thank you so much! . please direct me to reduce column Gap.

Comment: This more what you were looking for? Set margin auto on the `input-group` and added margin top/bottom to the `flex-group` class also set the input function to a width of 80%, this will reduce the space between your input elements by expanding their width.

Comment: Also, I can't express enough how valuable flexbox is to modern css design. You really should study it in great detail as it will make your coding so much more stream lined and easy. There is also grid design now as well check it out, they are just more tools at your disposal when designing with css...

Comment: Dear dale landry, I want to keep input width to maximum 50px. Then gap of the input boxes must be 15px. All adjustments of mine are unsuccessful. Need a help!

Comment: found a solution > .flex-group {
  display: flex;
    width: 60%;